# Hide attribute dropdown for a specific WooCommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

My requirement here is to hide attribute dropdown for a specific category in the archive page/loop of products as i have set default custom attribute visibility from product dashboard. 
In my small code so far it works, but it hides in all the categories as well.
Need help.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html','attrrj');
function attrrj(){
    global $product;

    //if(is_page(1881)){
        if ( has_term( 'cup','product_cat', $product->ID ) ) {           
            return 'ok';
        }   
    //}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **`$product`** WC_Product object you get the ID like this (Woocommerce compatibility versions):

```
global $product;

// get the product ID (Woocommerce compatibility versions)
$product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

if ( has_term( 'cup','product_cat', $product_id ) ) {           
    return 'ok';
}
```

This should work this time.

Comment: Even that didnt work. Can there be a possibility to trigger action hook conditionally